# Is for(1) always the same as do in perl?

Tags: perl

```
for(1){
  print 1;
}

do {
  print 1;
}
```

Is it true?

Or is there any special case these two doesn't equal?

Answer (score 13):

One difference is that `for(1)` sets $_ to the value of 1, as well:

```
for(1){
    print $_;  # prints 1
}
```

Also, `do` returns the value of the last command in the sequence:

```
my $x = do { 1 };  # $x = 1
my $y = for(1){ 1 }; # invalid
```

Answer (score 6):

You might really be looking for just plain curlies.

```
{
   print 1;
}
```

It has the following benefits:

- Creates a lexical scope (like `for (1)` and `do {}`).
- You can use `next`, `last` and `redo` in them (like `for (1)`).
- It doesn't mask `$_` (like `do {}`).

But

- It can only used where a statement is expected (like `for (1)`, but unlike `do {}`).

Therefore, `{ ... }` makes more sense than `for (1) { ... }`, and `do { ... }` is useful when you want to return a value.

Answer (score 5):

*About* the same.

- You can `next`, `last` and `redo` a `for` loop, but a `do` is not a loop--including as part of a `do`-`while` "loop". So in a non-trivial block, you couldn't be sure. However, this will work:

  ```
  do {{
      ...
  }};
  ```
- Also `do` will not automatically set `$_` to each member of the list, the way a bare `for` loop will.

Answer (score 1):

No.  They have different compilation properties and have different effects.  They are similar in only one dimension, that being that the code they introduce will not be looped over -- something they have in common with other constructs, including bare blocks and `(sub {...})->()`.

Here's an obvious difference:  `for (LIST) BLOCK` is a loop, whereas `do BLOCK` is an expression.  This means that

```
for (1) {
    say "Blurgh"
} unless 1;
```

doesn't compile, whereas

```
do {
    say "Blurgh"
} unless 1;
```

does.